# Google Script Uncaught ReferenceError: MailApp is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script

I,m making a script that sends an email to my gmail account when a user fils a form.

With the simplest call:

```
MailApp.sendEmail("theappowneraccount@gmail.com","The Subject","The text on body");
```

When the script gets this function shows the error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: MailApp is not defined

The script is inside a function called when a form is submitted.

```
function FormSubmit(){
 MailApp.sendEmail("theappowneraccount@gmail.com","The Subject","The text on body");
}
```

This is just the code, without any variable. Only plain text (at the moment).

Thanks (again).

Comment: most likely you are calling it from client javascript, not server side.

Comment: Could you explain that please? Thanks

Comment: show us how you call FormSubmit

Comment: You had reason. I was calling from client (the html file) instead from server (the .gs file). Thanks, your comment helped me.

Answer (score 0):

please review the documentation on MailApp [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))

You need to tell it what attribute goes where. Your code should look like this instead:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({to:"theappowneraccount@gmail.com",
                   subject:"The Subject",
                   body:"The text on body"}
                 );
```

Whitespaces not mandatory of course, so it can just as well be all in one line

Comment: Hi thanks. But that code makes the same error. I,ve just tested it.

Comment: Then it may have been something with the Google services. I just used the code and was able to set up a trigger on a form to run this. I received the e-mail without any problems.

Comment: Have you set the script to run as yourself, and then authorised it to send mail on your behalf?

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed the correct syntax according to Google's spec, then it should be an error with Google's systems. Raise an issue with them.

Comment: Hi. Tested any ways. Run as myself, as anyone, given rights to mail... So, It's possible to be issue. Going there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I was sure the answer was very simple, and of course...
Zig Mandel got that. I was trying into the client side. So the html file with some javascript, and it must be put on the .gs file.
Now works 
Thanks!